# Integral using trigonometric substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I'd like to ask for feedback on my calculation for this integral:

$$\int{\frac{dx}{2-\cos{x}}}$$

Using half-angle substitution:

$$t = \tan{\frac{x}{2}}$$
$$\cos{x} = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
$$dx = \frac{2dt}{1+t^2}$$

So

$$\int{\frac{dx}{2-\cos{x}}} = \int{\frac{1}{2-\frac{(1-t^2)}{1+t^2}}}\cdot\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}$$

$$= 2\,\,\int{\frac{1}{2(1+t^2)-(1-t^2)}}\,\,dt$$

$$= 2\,\,\int{\frac{1}{3(\frac{1}{3}+t^2)}}\,\,dt$$

$$= \frac{2}{3}\,\,\int{\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{\sqrt(3)^2})+t^2}}\,\,dt$$

Integrating the expression

$$=\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot \tan^{-1}{(\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}})}+c$$

$$=\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}\cdot \tan^{-1}{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\tan{(\frac{x}{2})})}+c$$

I believe the last expression should have $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ and not $\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}$, but in my calculation this appears correct.  Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After "Integrating the expression", it should be $\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{3}$

Comment: $\int\frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{1}{a}atan(\frac{x}{a})$

Answer (score 2):

Note also that it is $\tan^{-1}(\sqrt 3t)$, not $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt 3}\right)$.

Setting $t=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\tan\theta$ gives you
$$\begin{align}\frac 23\int\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\right)^2+t^2}dt&=\frac 23\int\frac{1}{\frac 13+\frac 13\tan^2\theta}\cdot\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt 3\cos^2\theta}\\&=\frac 23\cdot\frac{1}{\frac 13\cdot \sqrt 3}\int d\theta\\&=\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\tan^{-1}(\sqrt 3 t)+C\\&=\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt 3\tan\frac x2\right)+C\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the input, @mathlove, though it's a little confusing with the theta and x/dx mix.

Comment: @ptikobj: Well, sorry, but please clarify what you don't understand. Everything?

Comment: The original question stated in terms of cosx and tanx, and I worked in terms of the tangent half-angle substitution making t = tan(x/2).  Is the implication here that theta is (x/2)?  And in the integral, you've substituted dx (not dt?) for d(theta)/sqrt(3)cos^2(theta).  If you could just expand on those substitutions a bit, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @ptikobj: (1) $\theta\not=\frac x2$. I set $t=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\tan \theta$. (2) Since I set $t=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\tan\theta$, I got $dx=\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt 3 \cos^2\theta}$, not $dt$. (3) Another way is to follow Poppy's comment if you prefer.

Comment: @ptikobj: Sorry, I made a mistake. See the edit. I should have written $dt=\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt 3\cos^2\theta}$ in the above comment.

Comment: Ok, I see where you're going with the calculation.  However, I would still say that by using t-substitution, it makes more sense to express it in terms of $dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}\cos^2\theta}d\theta$, not $dx$.  It just looks more consistent with the terminology because it doesn't make sense to differentiate with respect to dx when you're using t instead of x.  Unless I'm mistaken here?  That is just how I've seen the t-substitution applied.  But thank you very much for clarifying!

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @ptikobj: sorry for confusing you. I hope it helps. You're welcome.

Comment: Yes, it's all good.